How can I fix the compilation issues in my Android project in Android Studio?
`Description:'
'I'm encountering several errors while trying to build my Android project. Could someone please help me troubleshoot these issues?'
'Errors:'
'Attribute android:allowBackup is not allowed here:10
Attribute android:hardwareAccelerated is not allowed here:11
Attribute android:networkSecurityConfig is not allowed here:12
Attribute android:icon is not allowed here:13
Attribute tools:targetApi is not allowed here:16
Unresolved class 'MainActivity':21
Attribute android:configChanges is not allowed here:22
Unresolved class 'PrivacyActivity':28
Code:`
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.company.gamename">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Game">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".PrivacyActivity" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.DELAY_APP_MEASUREMENT_INIT"
        android:value="true"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-9777034540867573~9744938716" />
</application>

